# Уменьшить нагрузку на сервер через Sleep()

Tags: php, клиент-сервер, веб-сервер

Вопрос. Если делать искусственную паузу после каждого запроса, например:

```
   $time_pause_querys = 5;
   if($_SESSION['time_query']){
        $defftime = time() - $_SESSION['time_query'];
        if($defftime < $time_pause_querys){
            flush();
            sleep($time_pause_querys - $defftime);
        } 
    }
```

смогу ли я таким способом уменьшить нагрузку на сервер. Таким образом я думаю тормозить тех умников, которые любят по 100 раз кликать на кнопку после получение результата, тем самым давая постоянные запросы на сервер.

Comment: Лучше на уровне js сделать disabled  эту кнопку на некоторое время.

Comment: Ваш костыль достаточно интересная идея. Если убрать sleep, то вполне можно использовать как временное решение.
Единственное, я бы делал вот этот игнор только для $_POST. Иначе юзер не сможет открыть сразу несколько страниц (в разных вкладках). Но, конечно, только как временное решение. По хорошему, нужно оптимизировать код или увеличивать мощность сервера, а не писать костыли.

Comment: Делая такое на сервере, вы серьёзно увеличите нагрузку на него из-за особенностей архитектуры php. А костыль на стороне клиента клиент сможет обойти, если захочет)

Comment: Если не секрет, каким образом?

Answer (score 1):

`sleep` не уменшит нагрузку, а скорее наоборот, процесс будет "висет", если таких процессов будет много, то сервер может и упасть,
Как предложил вам в коментах можно через js блокировать.
Можно пойти еще дальше, и добавить `капчу`, `csrf`, кешировать

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Farkhod Daniyarov за идею и вразумению. Вот такой костыль уже на стороне клиента:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  window['last_time'] = parseInt(new Date().getTime());
});

function Query(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var msg = $(this).serialize();
 $("#waiting").show();     // это такой большой div на весь экран  с крутилкой посередине и полупрозрачным фоном
 setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: 'server.php', data: msg, dataType: 'json',
   beforeSend: function(data){ $("#waiting").show(); },
   success: function(data){
    //обрабатываю данные от сервера
   },error: function(xhr, str){ console.log(xhr.responseText); },
   complete: function(data){   
    $("#waiting").hide();
    window['last_time'] = parseInt(new Date().getTime());
   }
  });
    }, PauseQuery());
 return false;
}

function PauseQuery(){
 var pause = 3000,
  time = parseInt(new Date().getTime()),
  defftime = time - window['last_time'];
 if(defftime < pause) pause = pause - defftime;
 else pause = 0;
 return pause;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```